# How to add Google Consent Android SDK to Flutter

Tags: java, android, flutter, dart

Im trying to add the Google Android Consent SDK to Flutter and connect to it using a MethodChannel. I've got the form popping up successfully and I am able to return some info back to my main.dart file on the Flutter side.

I'm having trouble getting the users choice they selected from the Google Consent Form returned back to me to the Flutter side so I can then save whether they selected to see PERSONALIZED or NON-PERSONALIZED ads back in my main.dart file. Im just using the boilerplate Flutter example app to achieve this. Any help is greatly appreciated.

**main.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(

        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  static const CHANNEL = const MethodChannel("flutter.native/helper");
  static const IS_EEA_OR_UNKNOWN_METHOD = "isEeaOrUnknown";

  bool isEeaOrUnknown = true;

  Future<bool> _isEeaOrUnknown() async {
    var result = await CHANNEL.invokeMethod(IS_EEA_OR_UNKNOWN_METHOD);

    if (result is bool) {
      print("isEEAOrUnknown: $result");
      return result;
    } else {
      print("WTF: $result");
      return true;
    }
  }

  void _callIsEea() {
    _isEeaOrUnknown().then((result) {
      Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3)).then((d) {
        setState(() {
          isEeaOrUnknown = result;
        });
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    _callIsEea();
  }


  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {

      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
    // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
    title: Text(widget.title),
  ),
  body: Center(
    // Center is a layout widget. It takes a single child and positions it
    // in the middle of the parent.
    child: Column(

      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        Text(
          "iisEeaOrUnknown: $isEeaOrUnknown",
        ),
        Text(
          '$_counter',
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
  floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
    onPressed: _incrementCounter,
    tooltip: 'Increment',
    child: Icon(Icons.add),
  ),
    );
  }
}
```

**MainActivity.kt**

```
package com.example.flutter_consent
import android.os.Bundle
import com.google.ads.consent.DebugGeography
import com.google.ads.consent.ConsentStatus
import com.google.ads.consent.ConsentInfoUpdateListener
import com.google.ads.consent.ConsentInformation
import com.google.ads.consent.ConsentFormListener
import com.google.ads.consent.ConsentForm
import io.flutter.app.FlutterActivity
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant
import java.net.MalformedURLException
import java.net.URL

class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {

  var form: ConsentForm? = null

  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(this)

    MethodChannel(flutterView, CHANNEL).setMethodCallHandler { call, result ->
      print("NATIVE method call")
      when (call.method) {
        IS_EEA_METHOD_NAME -> {
          print("NATIVE METHOD CALLED - $IS_EEA_METHOD_NAME")
          isEeaOrUnknown(result)
        }
        else -> {
          print("NATIVE METHOD CALL ERROR")
          result.notImplemented()
        }
      }
    }
  }


  private fun isEeaOrUnknown(result: MethodChannel.Result){
    val consentInformation = ConsentInformation.getInstance(this)

    //testing only
    consentInformation.debugGeography = DebugGeography.DEBUG_GEOGRAPHY_EEA
    //consentInformation.debugGeography = DebugGeography.DEBUG_GEOGRAPHY_NOT_EEA

    consentInformation.requestConsentInfoUpdate(arrayOf(PUBLISHER_ID), object : ConsentInfoUpdateListener {

      override fun onConsentInfoUpdated(consentStatus: ConsentStatus) {

        when (consentStatus) {
          ConsentStatus.PERSONALIZED -> {
            print("User selected personalized")


          }
          ConsentStatus.NON_PERSONALIZED -> {
            print("User non-personalized")


          }
          ConsentStatus.UNKNOWN -> {
            print("UNKNOWN")

          }
        }
      }

      override fun onFailedToUpdateConsentInfo(errorDescription: String) {
        print("ERROR $errorDescription")
        result.success(consentInformation.isRequestLocationInEeaOrUnknown)
        TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
      }

    })

    var privacyUrl: URL? = null
    try {
      privacyUrl = URL("http://www.privacyurl.com/")
    } catch (e: MalformedURLException) {
      e.printStackTrace()
      // Handle error.
    }
    form = ConsentForm.Builder(this, privacyUrl).withListener(object : ConsentFormListener() {
      override fun onConsentFormLoaded() {
        // Consent form loaded successfully.
        form!!.show()
      }

      override fun onConsentFormOpened() {
        // Consent form was displayed.
      }

      override fun onConsentFormClosed(
              consentStatus: ConsentStatus?, userPrefersAdFree: Boolean?) {
        // Consent form was closed.


      }

      override fun onConsentFormError(errorDescription: String?) {
        // Consent form error.
      }
    })
            .withPersonalizedAdsOption()
            .withNonPersonalizedAdsOption()
            .build()
            form!!.load()


  }

  companion object{
    const val CHANNEL = "flutter.native/helper"
    const val PUBLISHER_ID = "pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    const val IS_EEA_METHOD_NAME = "isEeaOrUnknown"
  }

}
```